# "which called", "which is called", "which was called"

Tags: phrase-meaning, relative-pronouns

Which version is better to say? What's the difference among them? I would like to understand the best version for this sentence and also under what circumstances I may use "which called", "which is called", "which was called".

> The Himalayas have the highest peak in the world, **which called** Mount Everest.
>
> The Himalayas have the highest peak in the world, **which is called** Mount Everest.
>
> The Himalayas have the highest peak in the world, **which was called** Mount Everest.

P.S. Is "which was called" used only for a thing which was in the past and it doesn't exist nowadays or we can use this form also when it exists nowadays?

Comment: to be called. What is your dog called? What was the dog you had before called? Passive construction.

Comment: Not only Passive Voice you can see here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+called%2C+which+is+called%2C+which+was+called+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=17&smoothing=50&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhich%20called%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhich%20is%20called%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhich%20was%20called%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwhich%20called%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhich%20is%20called%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhich%20was%20called%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Without a comma I don't think any of your sentences are saying what you want them to; your second is saying "Of all the peaks in the world called Mount Everest, the highest one is in the Himalayas."

Comment: The first is ungrammatical, the third could imply that the name has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 The Himalayas have the highest peak in the world, which called Mount Everest.

Unless a mountain got on the phone, this is incorrect. In any case it does not mean the same thing as the second sentence.

> 2 The Himalayas have the highest peak in the world, which is called Mount Everest.

Sentence (2) is the usual and natural way of putting this sentence.

> 3 The Himalayas have the highest peak in the world, which was called Mount Everest.

Sentence (3) suggests that the name used to be "Mount Everest" but is now something else, or that the mountain no longer exists, neither of which is correct.  Sentence (3) could be used if if it was part of a larger text about events at the time the name was first given to the mountain. Such a text, focusing on past events, might justify the use of the past tense. Otherwise the use of the past tense is confusing and not justified.

In general "which called" is using called as a verb, in the sense of "telephoned" or "spoke out to". The form "which is called" is giving the current name of something, and "which was called" is giving a previous name, or is focusing on past events, most often a prior name.

Comment: Can you simplify this sentence, in particular the usage of the word "applied"?: " Sentence (3) could be used if the text went on to discuss events at the time the name was applied to the mountain, focusing on that past time period."  Remember this is for learners.  The learner may have trouble understanding more unusual or advanced sentences.

Comment: @ Readin I have modified the sentence. Does it seem better for the purpose now?

Comment: Yes, I think it is easier to understand now.